# Bind selected item to view model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What is required to bind a ListBox selectedItem to my ViewModel? 
The view models SelectedClient is always null.

The ClientSelected is successfully called through a command called ClientClickedCommand. But when I try to access the view models SelectedClient in the ClientSelected method its null and throws an exception.

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbSlaves" Width="300" Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Slaves}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClient, Mode=TwoWay}"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Checked ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Button 
                        Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.ClientClickedCommand}"                    
                        >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MachineName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

VIEVMODEL (bound to DataContext)

```
        private MyClient _selectedClient;
    public MyClient SelectedClient
    {
        get {
            return _selectedClient;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _selectedClient)
            {
                _selectedClient = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedClient");
            }
        }
    }

    public string _infoText;
    public string InfoText { 
        get {
        return _infoText;
    }
        set {
            if (value != _infoText)
            {
                _infoText = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("InfoText");
            }
        }
    }

    private void ClientSelected()
    {
        var message = " - " + SelectedClient.MachineName + " was clicked";
        InfoText += message;

    }

ClientClickedCommand = new Command(ClientSelected,  ()=>  true); 



  public ICommand ClientClickedCommand
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

UPDATE: Im now trying to bind SelectedClient through CommandParameter like this

```
  <ListBox x:Name="lbSlaves" Width="600" Grid.Row="1" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Slaves}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="150" Height="60">
                    <CheckBox  IsChecked="{Binding Checked ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MachineName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <Button 
                        Content="Do something"  
                        Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.ClientClickedCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.SelectedClient, Mode=TwoWay}" />

                    <Button Content="Do another thing>" />

                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Are you selecting the item first and then click the button, or are directly clicking the button?

Comment: Im just clicking the item. How do i select them? What is the difference between selecting and clicking?

Comment: Well if you directly click the button defined in your `DataTemplate` without select the item containing this button before, you might need a CommandParameter

Comment: Ok thanks. So i ask again. What is the difference between selecting the item and clicking a button that is inside the button. I guess i dont understand how WPF handles this.

Comment: at some point the mouse click needs to be handled. if a button handles it, the underlying controls don't.

Comment: Ok thanks! I guess thats why its never selected. So how do i pass the clicked item to the Command? I was told this was the way but i guess i need to read up on CommandParameter.

Comment: you don't - get rid of the button. Who told you 'this was the way'?

Comment: @lokusking & Markus Hütter
Im updating my code to show how i try to bind CommandParameter to SelectedClient

Comment: SelectedClient is still not updated

Comment: did you read my updated answer? it's showing you how it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button might swallow the mouse click, but besides that, it's not clear where your `SelectedClient` property resides. It seems like it's in the `MyClient` class, whereas it should be in at the same level of `Slaves`.

Edit:
if you want to keep your own button use CommandParameter somewhat like this:

```
Command="{Binding  ElementName=MainGrid, Path=DataContext.ClientClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

I'm not sure about the works of `new Command (...)` but there are commands that take parameters so the next part should look like this:

```
private void ClientSelected(MyClient client)
{
    SelectedClient = client;
    var message = " - " + SelectedClient.MachineName + " was clicked";
    InfoText += message;

}
```

Comment: SelectedClient is in MyViewModel as well as Slaves. So they are on the same level.

Comment: does `MyClient` have a reference to `MyViewModel`? If so, you can use the button and in it's command, set the `SelectedClient` of it's 'parent' `MyViewModel` to itsself.

Comment: No it doesnt. MyClient is not knowing of the container it resides in. There must surely be another way.

Comment: @Lautaro I think the problem is that the button is consuming the mouse click event. By default your listboxitem should be highlighted when you click on it, it isn't getting highlighted right?

Comment: @Lautaro Either handle it at SelectedClient's setter, or the command, don't do both

Comment: @Jai You are right. When i click the button it does not get selected. However if i click the item outside of the button it gets selected. 

I dont understand the thing about command or setter. I think im just handling it in the command.

Comment: Added something to go with your 'including button' solution. but really - rather do it without the button. WPF does handle that, as you just discovered yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Most people have already told you the problem - the button inside your ListViewItem is consuming your click event. When you assign a command to a button, WPF will, in the background, subscribe to the button's click event. Default behavior of handling click event is to set `e.Handled = true;`, which causes other event arising from this single mouse click to stop working.

It is not too clear whether you have separate use for `SelectedClient` and the command. If all you want to know is that the user has clicked on that ListViewItem, you can simply not use commands.

```
public MyClient SelectedClient
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedClient;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != _selectedClient)
        {
            _selectedClient = value;
            ClientSelected();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedClient");
        }
    }
}
```

If selecting the ListViewItem has different objective from the button, then you need to consider why you need one button for each ListViewItem. Logically, if all the items need to do something of similar nature, you can put the button outside of the ListView. This way, the button does not mess up your ListView.

Comment: This solves it. Thank you! However i need to figure out how to include buttons in i each item as i have to extend the functionality. Each client needs three buttons that triggers different methods using that particular client.

Comment: @Lautaro It sounds to me that you don't need a ListView. You can simply use `ItemsControl`

Comment: actually now i realise that this way of doing it only lets me click once, then i have to unselect it. I guess i should look into ItemsControl.